# Can not find intersection for a solid and a line due to order of element creation

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I tried to get the intersection line for a vertical column solid and a beam centerline, but the result I got changed when the order of creation of these element changed.

Case 1: when I created 2 vertical columns then add a beam between them, I received correct result.

Case 2: When I created them beam first, then add 2 vertical columns to either end of the beam, the result is ridiculous:

1. Default join order (columns take preference): no intersection found
2. switch join order 1st time (beams take preference): no intersection found
3. switch join order 2nd time (columns take preference again): correct result

How does the order of element creation affect my code? how to fix this?

```
private static double GetIntersectionLength ( Solid solid, Line line )
    {
        SolidCurveIntersectionOptions opntions = new SolidCurveIntersectionOptions ();
        SolidCurveIntersection intersection = solid.IntersectWithCurve ( line, opntions );
        for ( int index = 0; index < intersection.SegmentCount; index++ )
        {
            Curve segment = intersection.GetCurveSegment ( index );

            if ( segment.Length > 0 )
                return ( segment as Line ).Length;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Expect result: intersection.SegmentCount = 1 and get the length of the intersection segment line, but I when debug intersection.SegmentCount = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered your identical question in the Revit API discussion forum on [`SolidCurveIntersection` cannot find intersection segment curve](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/solidcurveintersection-can-not-find-intersection-segment-curve/m-p/8597657). I repeat it here as well:

I would suggest using the ray casting functionality to shoot a ray along the beam location line instead of using SolidCurveIntersection.IntersectWithCurve. Look at the three FindReferencesByDirection SDK samples, especially FindColumns.

Here is a [blog post discussing that sample and the `FindReferencesByDirection` method](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/findreferencesbydirection.html) that provided access to the Revit API ray tracing functionality before the later introduction of the [`ReferenceIntersector` class](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/36f82b40-1065-2305-e260-18fc618e756f.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this solution require an 3D view while the application I'm currently working on must work on 2D view as well (plan view etc.). Thus, it can be technically correct but the trade off is not something that I can afford. Is there way that works on 2D view as well?

Comment: Besides, I still don't understand why the order of element creation in Revit can make such an impact while we have join order? Theoretically, if the elements are in the same join order, they should produce the same result (Case 2, step 1 and 3).

Comment: Ray tracing in 2D is not supported by the Revit API. However, that would not be hard for you to implement yourself. I cannot comment much on the join order... however, I can imagine that the join order and the geometrical evaluation and quite strongly decoupled.